# Dynamic cast to Interface

Tags: f#

According to the post http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/3616.aspx,
I need to use a function like the following to cast an object to an interface, I have run a test, this is still true, the bug of :?> is still not fixed.

```
let cast<'a> o = (box o) :?> 'a
let ci = {  new Customer(18, Name = "fred") with
                override x.ToString() = x.Name 
            interface ITalk with
                member x.Talk() =
                    printfn "talk1111111" }

let italk = cast<ITalk> ci

if not (italk = null) then
    italk.Talk()
```

Is there a more elegant way to write the above code. I am thinking to create another operator to replace :?>, but I can not get the generic type parameter passed in like the :?>

Answer (score 8):

Your `cast` function does not behave like the C# `as` operator - if the object can't be cast to the specified type, it will throw an exception rather than returning null. Therefore, checking to see if `italk = null` accomplishes nothing. If you want to make the `cast` function return null when the cast fails instead of throwing an exception, you could write it like this:

```
let cast<'a when 'a : null> o =
    match box o with
    | :? 'a as output -> output
    | _ -> null
```

However, this will only work on nullable types, which does not include structs or (by default) F# types. I might leave your `cast` function the way it is, and make a `tryCast` that uses options.

```
let tryCast<'a> o =
    match box o with
    | :? 'a as output -> Some output
    | _ -> None
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
ci |> tryCast<ITalk> |> Option.iter (fun it -> it.Talk())
```

In this case, `Option.iter` takes the place of your null test.

Comment: I create a operator "!>", like the following

let (!>) o = (box o) :?> 'a

let itx: ITalk = !> ci

itx.Talk()

but there drawback is that the type as to be input as annotation of the identifier, and there is no compile-time checking.

Answer (score 3):

Pattern matching provides a more idiomatic way to write this:

```
match box ci with
| :? ITalk as italk -> italk.Talk()
| _ -> ()
```

Or, even:

```
let bci = box ci
if bci :? ITalk then (bci :?> ITalk).Talk()
```

I keep a function like the following around, for when I know the type test will hold:

```
let coerce value = (box >> unbox) value

(coerce ci : ITalk).Talk()
```

Comment: @Fred: Sorry, typed it into the browser. You still need the call to `box` since object expressions are typed according to the first type implemented. I fixed the code.

Comment: @Fred: I updated my answer with another option that will work in your case.